# When I navigate the viewport black pixels appear

Tags: import

I am having an issue related to importing a rigged characters.  When I navigate the viewport black pixels appear.

[image]

windows 10
AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega mobile gx, 8.0 GB RAM
Leonovo ideapad 3

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Looks like a graphic card issue ... See if your device match's minimal requirements.